# Getting "Failed to resolve hostname" in MobileFirst Studio

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

Today I have installed newly fresh eclipse and mobileFirst (V7.1.0) Plugin. After successful installation, I have created MobileFirst Project and create the android environment. but i'm facing some strange issue after creating the android environment. even I am able to open my console without any issue. Below is the error.

NOTE: I have also tried to start eclipse with `eclipse -clean` command in terminal. also have uninstalled and reinstalled the mobileFirst plugin.

> Get MobileFirst Platform console URL failed - Failed to resolve
>   hostname.
>                                     java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.environment.MobileApplicationBuilder.getTokens(MobileApplicationBuilder.java:498)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.environment.ClientApplicationBuilder.createClientProjectBuilder(ClientApplicationBuilder.java:104)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.environment.ClientApplicationBuilder.getNewProjectBuilder(ClientApplicationBuilder.java:88)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.environment.ClientApplicationBuilder.getProjectBuilder(ClientApplicationBuilder.java:70)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.environment.MobileApplicationBuilder.build(MobileApplicationBuilder.java:172)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.buildEnvironment(ApplicationBuilder.java:288)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.buildEnvironments(ApplicationBuilder.java:247)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.build(ApplicationBuilder.java:111)
>                                     com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.build(ApplicationBuilder.java:87)
>                                     com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.build.apps.WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.buildApplication(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                     com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.build.apps.WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.runInWorkspace(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                     com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.build.apps.WorkspaceApplicationBuilder.buildApplicationSynchronously(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                     com.worklight.studio.plugin.wizards.newenvironment.helper.EnvironmentHelper$1.runInWorkspace(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                     org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>                                     org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the following options:

1. Kill the Java process and try again
2. In Eclipse > Servers view, double-click the *MobileFirst Development Server* entry and edit the `hostname` field with your IP address
3. Edit the hosts file - add your hostname.

   - Finder > Go > Go to folder > `/private/etc/hosts`
   - Add your hostname to the line starting with 127.0.0.1, for example:
     127.0.0.1 **mbp-idan** localhost
   - You may need to logout and login from the User

Comment: Try restarting the machine.

Comment: Note: I am running my eclipse and mobileFirst on MAC machine. already restarted.

Comment: Add another possible solution

Comment: I have tried your above solution,but no luck. it's not working. even now i'm facing the same issue on windows machine after updating my worklight.

Comment: Thanks Idan. It was something within my network. the issue went away by reseting my network adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89828/discussion-between-priyank-and-idan-adar).